# Virtualbox shared-folder auto-mount doesn't works

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mount

Host os: Win10
Guest os: ubuntu

in the vbox settings the checkbox "automount" is checked.
Unfortunately after each restart i have to mount my shared folder manually with "sudo mount -t vboxsf Projekte /media/sf_Projekte".

someone know why the vbox-automount function doesn't works for me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same host and guest systems and experience no issue with shared folder mounting when starting the guest OS.

Comment: Without knowing the OP's Windows build number, VirtualBox version and Ubuntu version it's impossible for your answer to suggest it should just work.